# SimpleJdbcInsert on MySQL DB returning BigInteger instead of Long after executeAndReturnKey method

Tags: java, mysql, key, spring-jdbc

I am running a simple insert query on a MySQL table with the following primary key declaration :

```
id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
```

They key returned is a BigInteger for some reason.  What changes do I need to make for a Long value to be returned as the key?

***EDIT***

I'm making a mini-ORM basically and the Long type is not known at compile time since it is a class parameter (`AbstractDao<T, I>`).  Essentially I need to be able to convert a Number to a Long without using anything that has long in it (Long.valueOf(), .longValue(), etc).

I do however have a Class instance that contains Long.class :

```
protected Class<?> idClass = ((Class<?>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[1]);
```

Can that instance somehow be used to perform the casting?  You cannot just cast a BigInteger to a Long, nor can you cast a String representation of BigInteger to a Long sadly.  If there was a way to access valueOf() from my class object this might work?

Comment: I changed the key to just INT and that method still returns a BigInteger.  Due to heavy reflection and generics usage I cannot just do Long.valueOf().  That method's return type is Number, why is it forcing a BigInteger on me?

Comment: problem is, the Long type is a class parameter (T) and is not known at runtime so i cannot use longValue since someone could parameterize this class with Integer if they wanted.  Basically I need to convert Number to Long with only an instance of Class<?> which, in this case, contains a Long.class value.

Comment: If that is your requirement, then **edit** the question and say that, so people reading the question will know what you need. Show the method you're referring to, to *clarify* what you're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

[`executeAndReturnKey(...)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.2.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/simple/SimpleJdbcInsert.html#executeAndReturnKey-java.util.Map-) returns a [**`Number`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html), so call [`longValue()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html#longValue--) if you want the result as a `long`.

If your method doesn't know the exact numeric type needed by the caller, let the caller do the `longValue()`. Alternatively, write multiple methods, for the various return types you want to support, e.g.

```java
public Number insertAndGetKey(...) {
    return ...executeAndReturnKey(...);
}
public int insertAndGetIntKey(...) {
    return insertAndGetKey(...).intValue();
}
public long insertAndGetLongKey(...) {
    return insertAndGetKey(...).longValue();
}
```

Comment: That method is part of Spring JDBC's SimpleJdbcInsert class which I cannot change

Comment: @Martin Huh? I'm talking about the method in **your** `AbstractDao` class that is using `SimpleJdbcInsert`. --- But maybe if you edited your question and ***clarified*** it, e.g. by showing where you actually make the call to `SimpleJdbcInsert`, we would all be talking about the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

This, although extremely ugly, works like a charm :

```
var method = idClass.getMethod("valueOf", String.class);
var result = method.invoke(null, key.toString());
```

This returns something I can then typecast to (I) without issues.  Please do let me know if you have a better solution to all this.  The original question being about the BigInteger return type, this can probably be avoided.